# NestJS x Graphql x Typegoose issue on sub resolver

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typegoose

I've got an issue with an interface type and some sub resolvers for the common part of the schema, here is my code and the issue. I might be wrong by declaring that way but I give you the goal and if you have any other design that matches the need, feel free to share it with me.

I'm using NestJS 7+, Typegoose, and nest Graphql with the CLI plugin that defines annotations auto.

I have an application where I have two kinds of users: **Professional** and **Individual**.

In the database, they are saved under a common document, fields that are in common lives in the document body, and specialized fields live in whether 
`individual`  or `legalEntity` key (it's an object).

```
@ObjectType()
class IndividualData {
  @prop()
  firstName: string;

  @prop()
  lastName: string;
}

@ObjectType()
class LegalEntity {
  @prop()
  tradeName: string;
}

@ObjectType({ description: "DO NOT USE, JUST FOR EXTENDING" })
export class User {
  @Field(() => ObjectId)
  _id: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => Date)
  createdAt: Readonly<Date>;

  @Field(() => Date)
  updatedAt: Readonly<Date>;

  @Field(() => EmailScalar)
  @prop({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Field(() => PasswordScalar)
  @prop()
  password: string;

  @prop()
  validationToken?: string;

  @prop()
  isValidated: boolean;

  @prop()
  isVolunteer: boolean;

  @prop()
  lastLogin: Date;

  @prop()
  photo?: string;

  @prop()
  phone?: string;

  @prop()
  city?: string;

  @prop()
  country?: string;

  @prop()
  individual?: IndividualData; // For individuals

  @prop()
  legalEntity?: LegalEntity; // For pro

  @Field(() => [ProductDTO])
  @arrayProp({ items: ObjectId })
  listings: Types.Array<ObjectId>; // Sale products as user

  @Field(() => VolunteersTeam) // Used in join
  @prop()
  volunteersTeam?: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => [Supplier]) // Used in join
  @arrayProp({ items: ObjectId })
  suppliers?: Types.Array<ObjectId>; // Suppliers space in which user is member
}
```

```
@InterfaceType({
  resolveType(item: UserDocument) {
    return item.legalEntity ? "ProfessionnalUserDTO" : "IndividualUserDTO";
  },
})
export class CurrentUserDTO extends OmitType(
  User,
  ["password", "validationToken", "legalEntity", "individual"],
  InterfaceType,
) {}

@ObjectType({
  implements: [CurrentUserDTO],
})
export class IndividualUserDTO extends CurrentUserDTO {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@ObjectType({
  implements: [CurrentUserDTO],
})
export class ProfessionnalUserDTO extends CurrentUserDTO {
  legalName: string;
}
```

Now here is my sub-resolver that is used to get common to both subfield which is named `suppliers`

```
@Resolver(() => CurrentUserDTO)
export class CurrentUserDTOResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly supplierService: SupplierService,
    private readonly volunteerService: VolunteerService,
    private readonly productService: ProductService,
  ) {}

  @ResolveField(() => [Supplier])
  async suppliers(@Parent() user: CurrentUserDTO) {
    return user.suppliers.length > 0
      ? this.supplierService.find({ _id: { $in: user.suppliers } })
      : [];
  }
}
```

I'm now getting

`(node:58160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined`

Any idea?
Looks like du to `@Resolver(() => CurrentUserDTO)`, `CurrentUserDTO` does not exists in this.objectTypes at compileExternalFieldResolverMetadata

If I try to add `@ObjectType()` under `@InterfaceType` at `CurrentUserDTO`

I get `Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "CurrentUserDTO".` which is normal…
Therefore I've no idea…
How do define sub_resolver for the interface type
I'm dead with that…

Do you have any suggestions / ideas?

Thank you,
Andréas

Answer (score -1):

As you cannot define resolvers in NestJS for interface (and in grpahql generally) you could achieve that behavior by doing what's following:

```
// One annotation per things that implement my CurrentUserDTO interface
@Resolver(() => IndividualUserDTO)
@Resolver(() => ProfessionnalUserDTO)
export class CurrentUserDTOResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly supplierService: SupplierService,
    private readonly volunteerService: VolunteerService,
    private readonly productService: ProductService,
  ) {}

  @ResolveField(() => [Supplier])
  async suppliers(@Parent() user: CurrentUserDTO) {
    return user.suppliers.length > 0
      ? this.supplierService.find({ _id: { $in: user.suppliers } })
      : [];
  }
}
```